# Invoking a process whenever someone logins through SSH

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to invoke a ruby script whenever anyone tries to SSH into the server(say Ubuntu 14.04).  
Like for example someone is trying to login with ssh root@serverip and my ruby script should be called upon and the login process should continue only if the script returns true and if returns false the connection should be closed.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397674/run-scripts-automatically-in-server-after-ssh-connection

Answer (score 3):

To fulfill your requirements, you should also work with `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable, if you use `ForceCommand` option:

```
ForceCommand /path/to/script && $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

This will run your script and based on the exit status of the `/path/to/script`, it will run the user command or exit session.

Comment: That's awesome but a small question, how can I exit the session from the script? Like throw some sort of exception or something? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: If the script returns non-zero exit code, the original command will not get executed, command ends and the session exits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488014/usr-bin-env-ruby-no-such-file-or-directory-at-ssh-login @Jakuje

Comment: you sure that with zero exit code it does get executed and vice versa? I couldn't see that. I even checked with $? and it said zero, but still connection was closed :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the **ForceCommand** parameter in the sshd_config file of your server. it's fairly straightforward and well documented online :)

You enter at the bottom of the config file:

```
ForceCommand /path/to/script
```

Not so sure if you can check for certain conditions and terminate the connection, however this might guide you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by a friend in an answer, exit code based execution didn't work for me.

Here's a workaround :-

As mentioned by some folks, I used this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`ForceCommand /path/to/script`

Then in the script I opened the bash if they satisfied certain conditions. For example in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ condition ]
then 
bash #This will open bash if condition is satisfied. 
//login
fi
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This will basically break all user commands put on commandline (also `scp` for example). You might check also for the variable `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, if it is set, try to execute it. But yes, this is partial workaround.