# /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory at SSH login

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, ssh, rvm

I'm trying to run a ruby script from inside of a bash script at SSH login. I did put the `ForceCommand /etc/ssh/MyScript.sh && $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` inside sshd_config and inside MyScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash   
./MyRubyScript.rb
```

In my MyRubyScript.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Some Ruby logic
puts 'Hey'
```

I wanted that MyRubyScript.rb to execute at the event that any one tries to login through SSH.
But whenever I try to SSH login into the server, I get the following error.

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Please help me out!

P.S. I tried to put the Ruby file directly into the `sshd_config` but it's still the same.

Comment: Where on the system is the ruby program installed?

Comment: by running `which ruby` I got this `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby`
Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Make sure `MyRubyScipt.rb` doesn't have CRLF line endings.

Comment: If you are running ruby with rvm you'r system may not know where to find a global ruby version. For sure you might be able to execute `ruby MyRubyScript.rb` and I guess it'll also work if you change the shebang to `#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby` but that obviously is not a good idea :)You may want to either install a ruby in your system environment or execute the script with ruby.

Comment: It's probably the case that your RVM Ruby isn't ending up in your path when you use SSH.

Comment: If you can run `/usr/bin/env: ruby -v` from the command line after you login, it's probably just that you're attempting to run this before the RVM scripts have loaded (by default, at the end of your `.bash_profile`).  Verify that RVM has loaded, and consider moving it higher in your `.bash_profile` if there will be dependencies on RVM and Ruby.

Comment: I eventually changed the shebang and it worked but looking for a better solution.m